# Linear subspace of commutating matrices of dimension 4

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

We have linear space of matrices of Real numbers of size $2 \times 2$; There exists a subspace of matrices $2 \times 2$, where $AX = XA$ ($X, A$ are matrices with size $2 \times 2$)

Is there any way I can imagine what does this subspace looks like in that linear space? Or any way how to visualize that subspace in that space?

Thanks

Comment: It's a system of four linear equations in four unknowns. So, the solution space is a subspace of a 4D space. Can you visualise a 4D space? Leonard Susskind says (probably in [this talk](https://youtu.be/KR3Msi1YeXQ), IIRC) all but a few people he knows cannot. I cannot too.

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be a fixed matrix, and you're looking for all matrices $X$ that commute with it?

Comment: @JohnHughes Exactly. I'm sorry, forgot to mention that. We had a fixed A (I forgot how exactly it was) and we were supposed to prove that it's a subspace and find its dimension and basis. What I want to do now is to somehow "visualize" or show how does that subspace look or what is that subspace in R^(2,2).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be a very satisfying answer, but ...

As usual, things get easier when you choose the right basis.

First, if $A$ is the zero matrix, then the subspace (which I'll call $S$) is all of $M_{22}$.

Second if $A$ has a single eigenvector for a nonzero eigenvalue, then there's an invertible matrix $Q$ with 
$$
Q^{-1} A Q = \pmatrix{k & 0 \\ 0 & 0} 
$$
Note that if $AX = XA$, then 
$$Q^{-1} A Q \cdot Q^{-1} X Q = Q^{-1} AX Q = Q^{-1} XA Q=Q^{-1} X Q \cdot Q^{-1} A Q$$.

In short, instead of looking for matrices that commute with $A$ in the standard basis, we can look for those that commute with $A' = Q^{-1} A Q$ in the $Q$ basis. Doing so yields exactly the diagonal matrices.

The preceding argument works because the Jordan normal form of $A$ is $A'$, and we can simply work in the Jordan basis. Well, there are three more cases to consider: (a) the matrix $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues, both nonzero, (b) the matrix $A$ has two identical nonzero eigenvalues, and is a multiple of the identity, (c) the matrix has one (repeated) nonzero eigenvalue, and its Jordan form has a "1" in the upper right corner and (d) the matrix has, as its Jordan form, $\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}$.

You can work through the analogous computations for each of these cases. Case b is easy: the set of commuting matrices is "all matrices". For case $d$, the answer is all matrices $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$ with $a = d$ and $c = 0$, i.e, the solution subspace is a product of the diagonal line in the $ad$-plane and the horizontal line in the $bc$-plane. Cases a and c are messier.

Comment: I have read your answer couple times, but I'm not able to understand it. Maybe an example would help. I got matrice A from the example - \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} . Can you show it to me on that exact A? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let $S = \pmatrix{0.8507 & 0.5257 \\ 0.5257 & -0.8507}$ and $D = \pmatrix{2.618 & 0.o \\ 0.0 & 0.382}$; then $S^t D S$ is (approximately) your matrix. So if you use the columns of $S$ as a basis for the plane, then the matrix for your transformation becomes diagonal, and you can see it as stretching a lot in the $x$ direction and compress a bit in the $y$-direction. Now if $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$ commutes with this diagonal matrix you can (algebraically) see that $b = c = 0$, but $a$ and $d$ can be anything. Hence, there's a 2-plane of matrices that commute with yours.